# Restrict Azure DevOps Boards permissions by Team

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I've been trying to make this setup to work and I need some help.

How can I isolate team's boards and work items so that members of one team cannot view & edit other team's boards and work items?

[image]

My department wants to use a single ADO project for the development of multiple systems. Reading thought Msft's documentation, it is even [recommended to do so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops#when-to-add-another-project):

> In general, we recommend that you use a single project to support your
> organization or enterprise. A single project minimizes the maintenance
> of administrative tasks and supports the most optimized /
> full-flexibility cross-link object experience.
>
> Even if you have many teams working on hundreds of different
> applications and software projects, you can most easily manage them
> within a single project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of "team ownership" of workitems in Azure DevOps. Instead the each workitem belong to an Area Path. Area paths can then be added to one or multiple teams (see [Add area path to team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#set-team-area-paths)). The workitems belonging to Area Paths of a team is what is shown on the teams board.

In order to achieve what you describe you need to first ensure that each team has their own area paths that are not shared with any other team (there is no limitation against this in Azure Devops as is). Once there are no shared Area Paths you can [set permissions on the area paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#set-permissions-area-path)

> Area path permissions let you grant or restrict access to edit or
> modify work items, test cases, or test plans assigned to those areas.
> You can restrict access to users or groups. You can also set
> permissions for who can add or modify areas or iterations for the
> project.

I would recommend to remove all permissions from the root area path so that no permissions are inherited and assign only `View Workitems in this node` and `Edit workitems in this node` to the team that is owning the area path. While it is technically possible to leave the root area permissions as is and deny the abovementioned permissions for all other teams instead, that quickly becomes an administrative overhead and source of error (for example, adding a new team would require all existing area paths to be updated in such a scenario)

I would still recommend evaluating the single project setup even though it is a recomendation from Microsot. Your strict boundaries that do not even allow read access between workitems voids many of the advantages of the single project setup unless you are setting up some [hierarchial team structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/configure-hierarchical-teams?view=azure-devops) where a management team has access into multiple area paths and thus can view an aggregated board or do cross team searches.

Another thing to consier when having multiple teams that essentially work in silos in the same project is how tags work. The tags are project wide and thus a tag taht is created by team A will show up in the list of tags also for Team B (in autocomplete fields etc), which can be confusing.

Comment: can we not restrict the board access also? after doing this I was able to restrict work item view/edit access but the board up top on left is still there and mebers can navigate to that but they see blank board. It would be good if they only see the team board they have access to.. is there any way?

Comment: @rohit Unfortunately not. As I mentioned in the answer there is no concept of team ownership of workitems, nor is there any permissions for being able to see a team. Someone with access to the project will be able to see the boards of all teams in that project. The boards may look different (or even be empty) to different people based on the permissions on the area paths connected to the teams. To achieve the isolation you are asking for you would need to put the teams in different projects.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but can I ask: when I view the root area perms I see numerous groups (Builders, Contributors, Readers, Project Collection Build Service accounts, Project Collection Test Service Accounts), plus a user called "<projectname> Build Service". When you say to remove *all* permissions to avoid inheritance, I assume I should only remove "Contributors" (and possibly "Builders" & "Readers", although these have no members) as these appear to be "user" groups? The rest sound like "system" groups that presumably might cause problems if removed?

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict the team users with [Area path permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#create-child-nodes-modify-work-items-under-an-area-path). Please refer to the steps below:

1. Create 2 teams: (Project settings -> Teams -> New Team)

[image: e.g.: Test1 Group for Test1 team, TestTeamGroup for TestTeam team]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

2. Add team members to the corresponding Team.
3. [Define area paths and assign to a team.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) (Project settings -> Project configuration -> Areas)
4. Navigate to the specific Team, and set the default Area path for the team.
5. Set permission for the Areas by right clicking the Area -> Security. For example, set permissions for Areas of Team A:

[image]

6. Search Team B and set the following permission to Deny:

   View permissions for this node - Deny

   View work items in this node - Deny

[image]

7. Thus the members in Team B cannot see the work items in Backlog/Board of Team A .

Comment: Explicitly denying access for certain groups quickly becomes an administrative burden, consider for example adding a new team, then all existing teams area paths needs to be updated otherwise the new team will inherit rights to it. Removing the standard privileges from the root area path and explicitly assign allow permissin for each team only on their area paths would be more robust and less admin

Comment: @danielorn completely agree with it, you should add that as an answer..

Answer (score 1):

In the project settings, Project Configuration/Team configuration -> Areas -> Select the respective area (Team), click on the three dots and select Security. Set the permission according to your need.

[image: permission sessions team configuration]